# Automatic click an element one by one at same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I run the fiddle, the text "a" should be changed automatic without `click` event, and it must changed one by one with a delay, How do I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = ".pictures";
  var delay = 2 * 1000; //2 Seconds

  function change() {
    $(element).one('click', function() {
      $(this).text("Changed");
    })
  }

  change();
  setInterval(change(), delay);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
```

**[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa2a15um/)**

Comment: `setInterval(change, delay);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `trigger()` the click handler in the `change` function. Additionally you need to pass the function reference to `setInterval()` method, also use `clearInterval()` to cancel the action once all elements are clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Cache elements
  var element = $(".pictures");

  //variable to maintain index of clicked item
  var i = 0;

  //2 Seconds
  var delay = 2 * 1000;

  //Bind event handler
  element.one('click', function() {
    $(this).text("Changed");
  })

  function change() {
    if (i == element.length && interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    //get element at index using .eq() and trigger click handler
    element.eq(i++).trigger('click');
  }

  //Execute on page load
  change();

  //On interval
  var interval = setInterval(change, delay);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
```

[**Update Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gk0ftLeq/1/)

Comment: @EngkusKusnadi Here's pure native version https://jsfiddle.net/jr5of7nr/2/

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var elementSelector = ".pictures";
        var delay = 2 * 1000; //2 Seconds

        function change(element, delayIndex) {
            setTimeout(function(){
              element.text("Changed");
            }, delay*delayIndex);
        }

        $(elementSelector).each(function(i, v){
            change($(v), i);
        });

    });
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa2a15um/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get an element based on the index and use a counter variable to select one by one.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = ".pictures";
  var delay = 2 * 1000; //2 Seconds
  var $ele = $(element),
    i = 0;

  function change() {
    // get the element by index and update
    $ele.eq(i++).text("Changed"); 
    // clear the interval when updated all
    if (i == $ele.length) clearInterval(inter);
  }

  change();
  var inter = setInterval(change, delay);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = ".pictures";
  var delay = 2 * 1000; //2 Seconds
  
 
  

  function change(el) { 
      $(el).text("Changed");    
  }
  
  $.each($('.pictures'), function(i, el){

    $(el).css({'opacity':0});
      change(el);
    setTimeout(function(){
       $(el).animate({
        'opacity':1.0
       }, 450);
    },1000 + ( i * 1000 ));

  });

 
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oa2a15um/4/)**

Use `index` to refer to the next element and stop the interval when the index equal the number of `div`'s :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var element = ".pictures" ;
  var delay   = 2 * 1000 ; //2 Seconds
  var index = 0;
  var limit = $(".pictures").length ;

  $(element).one('click', function() {
    $(this).text("Changed");
  })

  function change(){
    if(index<limit)
      $(element+':eq('+index+')').click();
    else
      clearInterval(interval);

    index++;
  }

  change(index);
  var interval = setInterval(change, 500);
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var element = ".pictures" ;
  var delay   = 2 * 1000 ; //2 Seconds
  var index = 0;
  var limit = $(".pictures").length ;

  $(element).one('click', function() {
    $(this).text("Changed");
  })

  function change(){
    if(index<limit)
      $(element+':eq('+index+')').click();
    else{
      clearInterval(interval);
      console.log('Intervel stopped.');
    }

    index++;
  }

  change(index);
  var interval = setInterval(change, 500);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

one by one with an index and clear interval when finished

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<div class="pictures">a</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = ".pictures";
  var delay = 2 * 1000; //2 Seconds
  var tempIndex = 0;

  var interv = setInterval(change, delay);

  function change() {
    if(tempIndex < $(element).length){
        $(element+":eq("+tempIndex+")").text("Changed");
        tempIndex++;
    }else{
        clearInterval(interv);
    }
  }

})
</script>
```